# How to access an aws s3 bucket using Access Key ID and secret access Key?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a free account on AWS and somebody shared me an Access key ID and  Secret access key to access their s3 bucket.

I am new in AWS, how can I access their s3 bucket using AWS web console?

Answer (score 1):

Via the AWS Console it's not possible if the IAM User has no console permissions. Use S3 Tool e.g. s3browser, cyberduck or the awscli.

List of tools

- https://aws-blog.de/amazon-aws-tools.html
- https://proprivacy.com/cloud/comparison/amazon-s3-user-interface-tools